# How can I open an application without making it appear (at all) in the Unity launcher?

Tags: 12.04, unity, startup, desktop-environments, background-process

I want to open a startup application in background, but i dont want too see it in common **Unity** panel at the left side.

At the worst it will be at the task bar (where there is a clock).
Thanks for your time.

PrtSc: running "test.desktop" with "gcalctool". You see its icon with picture "question mark!"  [Link to PrtSc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDIiI.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'd be possible in Unity, because the top bar is reserved for menus. But if you want it, you can install any other Desktop Environment like XFCE or LXDE. Then you can install some dock like AWN, Cairo Dock, etc.

**Xubuntu with dock**

[image]

**Lubuntu with dock**

[image]

*More on docks*: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/04/you-choose-the-best-dock-for-ubuntu-poll.

Comment: Thanks for article about docks. But now i stay on Unity and i hope the trouble may be solved.

Answer (score 1):

The way an application is represented in Unity is defined in its `.desktop` file. In case we do not want an icon to appear in the Unity Launcher we may call an application from a .desktop file where we do not reference an icon, e.g.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Calculator No Icon
Comment=Perform arithmetic, scientific or financial calculations
Exec=gcalctool
Terminal=false
Icon=
Type=Application
```

You can test this by saving this example in `~/.local/share/applications/<anyname>.desktop`. Give this file executable permission to be able to run it from double click in Nautilus. Notice that the icon in the Launcher will be replaced by an empty space.

[image]

There is no guarantee that removing the `Icon=` reference in its .desktop file prevents showing an icon as every window may define an icon representation at runtime. This can be seen when we remove the `/usr/share/applications/gcalctool.desktop` file. Still gcalctool will show its icon in the Launcher when run from a terminal.

In any case we are not able to remove the empty placeholder for a graphical application that opens a window on the desktop.

Comment: 1. I want to hide a graphical app TeamViewer at all. Is it impossible, right? 2. I have opened this file, but there are any same strings (Exec=gksu /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator) in it. Could i add new?

Comment: Sorry, could i make "try.desktop" instead or addition old file? Will it file launch after reboot?

Comment: I tried with gcalctool (even with "NoDisplay=true"). However there is a icon at the common panel which picture is "question mark". Sad ;/

Comment: Interesting moment: when i close Rhythmbox it does not close. However its icon disappear.

Comment: Sorry, could you tell me about situation ".desktop" and gcalctool ? is it graphical application or not? It does not disappear from Unity Launcher (test with gcalctool).

Comment: Yes,Sir!I am talking about the same process. But there is not empty placeholder. I can see square icon with picture "question mark" at the Laucher (and application window).

Comment: Sir! It has done. Window of terminal is external window to show you the content of ".desktop" file.

Comment: What happens when you add the following line to the .desktop file `Icon=` (just nothing after that)?

Comment: I have added, but panel's icon doesn't change. There is change for icon at my desktop only.

Comment: Hmm - no further idea at the moment, sorry.